# No Trailing slash "/" in url redirects to http and appends port number in domain

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a URL problem and don't know much how these work, still new to these stuff.

For example I have a website called https://www.samplesite.com/.
The problem here is that when I browse to a folder with a trailing slash in the end like
https://www.samplesite.com/folder/

it loads the page fine

But

When I try to browse like this 
https://www.samplesite.com/folder
with no trailing slash at the end it redirects me to http://www.samplesite.com:81/folder/ and the site can't be reached.

I am redirected to an http and the port number is appended in the domain.

My site already has SSL certificate. I have an IIS URL reqrite set up but don't know much about that.
This is my C# code that i am currently working on but it doesnt work.

in Global.asax Application_BeginRequest

```cs
var urlPort =HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().ToLower();

string port = ":81";

if (urlPort.Contains(port))
{
string newUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(":" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port, string.Empty);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(newUrl);
}
```

in web.config > securePages.config

```cs
<securePages forceNonSSL="true" port="443" address="https://samplesite.local">
  <templates>
    //I have a list of templates
    <add name="/Templates/Public/samplePage.aspx" />
  </templates>

  <paths>
      <add name="/" matchOption="StartsWith" />
  </paths>
</securePages>
```

URL:
https://www.samplesite.com/folder

Expected:
https://www.samplesite.com/folder/

Result:
http://www.samplesite.com:81/folder/

Can anyone explain me what is happening?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the web.config and update your question with information about what you have in the "rewrite" element of the config.   I suspect that a mistake in one of the rewrite rules is causing the problem

Comment: I don't have anything written in my URL rewrite. Also in web.config i have no redirect rules written there.

Comment: Are you using any other modules such as "urlrewritingnet" or any other systems in place that are meant to handle missing trailing slashes?

Comment: I believe I do have something. I edited the problem.

Comment: Based on that you seem to be using this module https://github.com/webadvanced/Secure-Page-manager-for-asp.net to manage your HTTPS redirects - is that correct?     If so, is there any reason why you want some pages to be HTTPS and some to be HTTP?   If not, then the solution may be to change how your HTTPS redirects are being handled, such as using the standard rewrite config.   I'm not familiar with the 'securePages' module, so don't know much about the specifics of how it works (or it's quirks!)

Comment: i think it's the way how trailing slash work. I have tried going to SSL certified pages and when i take out the trailing slash at the end it fails. Also tried http://www.samplesite.com/folder/ and it works fine it redirects to https.

Comment: I was wondering if the "path" part of that config section might be relating to the issue - though thinking about it that does look like it might just be specifying that everything from / should be HTTPS.   Can you see if you have any other modules/components/settings installed that are specifically there to handle a missing trailing slash?